# Is it possible to concatenate values in Angular ng-options

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-options

Basically, I'm trying to populate a select box but concatenate values from the `first_name` column and `last_name` column.

What I want to do (doesn't work):

```
<select ng-model="buyers" ng-options="b.id as (b.first_name + " " + b.last_name) for b in buyers"></select>
```

What does work:

```
<select ng-model="buyers" ng-options="b.id as b.first_name for b in buyers"></select>
```

Comment: I have done this before and it does work. My syntax `s.subsidiary.sid._value_ as s.subsidiary.subsidiary_no._value_ + ' :' + s.subsidiary.subsidiary_name._value_ for s in subsidiaries`. The only difference I can see is that I did not use parentheses. Try removing them and see if it works.

Comment: Another option would be to create a property called full_name with the concatenated value before binding the data.

Comment: okay the problem was the double quotes, needed single.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

The quotes are important. It won't work with double quotes inside double quotes or single quotes inside single quotes.

What does work:

```
<select ng-model="buyers" ng-options='b.id as (b.first_name + " " + b.last_name) for b in buyers'></select>
```

Comment: I added this answer to remove the question from the list of unanswered AngularJS questions.

Comment: Just a note about something that tripped me up: The quotes are important. It won't work with double quotes inside double quotes or single quotes inside single quotes.

Comment: Absolutely  dbl quotes inside dbl quotes don't work, because they end the current string and start another one.  You have to mix up the quotes like above.

Comment: Instead of this use like (b.first_name +'&nbsp;'+ b.last_name). This will work.

Comment: for me, `'b.id as (b.first_name + b.last_name) for b in buyers'` has perfectly worked.

Answer (score 4):

You can concatenate a string using this synthax:

```
ng-options="i.x + ' ' + i.y for i in items"
```

The following snippet concatenate `firstname` and `lastname`:

```js
angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.names = [{firstname: 'Jon', lastname: 'Snow'},
                  {firstname: 'Rob', lastname: 'Stark'},
                  {firstname: 'Ned', lastname: 'Stark'}];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <select ng-model="selected" ng-options="n.firstname + ' ' + n.lastname for n in names"></select>
  selected: {{selected}}
</div>
```

<sub>Note that parenthesis are not *required*, but it may improve *readability*.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

try this instead

```html
<select ng-model="buyers" ng-options="b as (b.first_name + " " + b.last_name) for b in buyers">
</select>
```