# How to also show the option.lastname data inside this "convertToInt (option.id) as option.name for option in owners" in angular?

Tags: angularjs

I need to add `option.lastname` data along with option.name data inside option.

I found this way to convert the id to int works perfect but I am not being able to bring me the last name, it only leaves me one.

```
<select class="form-control" 
        ng-model="dog.owner_id" 
        convertToNumber  
        ng-change="selectOwner(dog.owner_id)" 
        ng-options="convertToInt(option.id) as option.name for option in owners">
   <option value="">Seleccione</option>
</select>
```

Before I had it like this but since I had to convert the ID to int it did not work for me:

```
<option value="@{{option.id}}" ng-repeat="option in owners">
      <b> @{{option.name}} @{{option.lastname}}</b>
</option>
```

Comment: Note that `<option>` only supports text content and not html. Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to concatenate values in Angular ng-options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20101793/is-it-possible-to-concatenate-values-in-angular-ng-options)